# Converting date strings like "Aug 2 2019 10:22am" into valid dates in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, date, datetime, excel-formula

I have about 600 rows in Excel with date strings like so:

```
Aug 2 2019 10:22am
Aug 20 2019 9:30am
Aug 28 2019 8:58pm
Dec 29 2018 11:54am
```

I am trying to convert these strings into `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm` values that Excel recognizes as actual dates (e.g. so I can sort from most recent to least recent).

Any ideas how to do this? I tried researching the DATEVALUE() function, but wasn't able to get that to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If all dates follow same pattern all you need to do is 1) separate the date from the time, 2) reorder the date parts, 3) use the datevalue and the time value, 4) sum both results in one cell, 5) apply a format to the cell, 6) copy formula to the other cells, 7) order on that cell

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2010 Professional Plus or later versions of Excel, try **Power Query**.

Simply highlight the range of data, load it (`From Table` function under `Data` tab) to the power query editor, which will automatically recognise your sample data as date and time, then you can sort it as you would normally do in Excel, then **Close and Load** the output to a new worksheet (by default).

Here is what I get from Power Query:

[image: Result]

> It can also be done using excel formulas but you will need to break the string down and reorganise them so the **DATEVALUE** and **TIMEVALUE** function can recognise the sub-strings and then add them up to get a valid date+time. It will be faster using power query in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This formula will convert the string into an unambiguous date (assuming an English language version) which Excel can understand:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1)-1,0," ")," ",", ",2)
```

Then just format as you wish.

[image]